# Duplicate code from identical objects in separate namespaces

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I am writing a console app to make managing a local SSRS instance easier using the [ReportExecution2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005?view=sqlserver-2016) and [ReportService2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010?view=sqlserver-2016) libraries each providing different functions. To work with existing reports I have to read XML strings from the ReportServer database which holds the reports parameters, parse them, and use this information to build objects used when communicating with the server. To do this I wrote a simple function shown below

```
public static ParameterValue[] RebuildParameters(string parameters) {

        //setup xml
        XDocument main = XDocument.Parse(parameters);
        List<XElement> pElements = main.Descendants("ParameterValue").ToList();

        //rebuild param list
        ParameterValue[] newParams = new ParameterValue[pElements.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (XElement param in pElements) {
            newParams[i] = new ParameterValue();
            newParams[i].Name = param.Element("Name").Value.ToString();
            newParams[i].Value = param.Element("Value").Value.ToString();
            i++;
        }

        return newParams;
}
```

Everything was going fine until I needed to use this helper function for the two separate namespaces. The ParameterValue class exists in both namespaces ([Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2010.parametervalue?view=sqlserver-2016) and [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.parametervalue?view=sqlserver-2016)) but I cannot explicitly cast between them. I've tried also setup a generic function but I cannot assign the Name or Value since the type is unknown.

```
public static T[] RebuildParameters<T>(string parameters) where T : new() {
        //setup xml
        XDocument main = XDocument.Parse(parameters);
        List<XElement> pElements = main.Descendants("ParameterValue").ToList();

        //rebuild param list
        T[] newParams = new T[pElements.Count];
        foreach (XElement param in pElements) {
            newParams[i] = new T();
            //not allowed
            newParams[i].Name = param.Element("Name").Value.ToString();
            newParams[i].Value = param.Element("Value").Value.ToString();
        }
        return newParams;
    }
```

What is the best way to write a single helper method that can be used by both classes from a different namespaces knowing the code will be identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that those types cannot be cast because they represent completely different types. However, after looking at them they seem like very simple objects which gives you the option to map them. Assuming both are available to you in the same form that the linked docs indicate you should be able to do this:

```
public ReportService2010.ParameterValue Map(ReportExecution2005.ParameterValue data)
{
    return new ReportService2010.ParameterValue()
    {
        Label = data.Label,
        Name = data.Name,
        Value = data.Value
    };
}

public ReportService2005.ParameterValue Map(ReportExecution2010.ParameterValue data)
{
    return new ReportService2005.ParameterValue()
    {
        Label = data.Label,
        Name = data.Name,
        Value = data.Value
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While this works, once I have the array of Parameter values in one namespace, I now have a function that will cycle through them and remap to the other namespace... which is essentially a repeat of the original function. Is there no way to to create a single function that does what a I need... generics, interface applied to those classes, or anything else? If this is the best approach I can accept that, I was just hoping for something a bit cleaner.

Comment: @KorbenDallas I don't think I'm following you. When you say _essentially a repeat of the original function_ what original function are you referring to? Could you elaborate on what behavior you'd expect from a single function?

Comment: my original function (first code block), parses xml string then loops through results to create an array of ParameterValues. From you suggestion I can do this for ReportService2005, but if ReportService2010 array is needed, I loop through it again to map the values to the correct namespace/class. A single function would only require a single loop. Parse XML -> Loop through and created the desired ParameterValue Objects -> Return correct namespace array. No mapping or converting, which is why I was chasing after the generic function. Again, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Ok, I don't think a straight generic function will get you there since any constarint will be an `and`. But, another possibility would be to use [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html), it should be able to map your classes without configuration since the property names are matched.

Comment: Another thought: if you have both of these types represented as basic xml you should be able to deserialize that xml form to either type. That would be easier than parsing the xml and you'd get both types.

Comment: This was what I needed! Instead of manually parsing the XML I can just create a instance of XmlSeralizer in each separate class of the desired type I need. Then I can deserialize the data and remove the helper class entirely. Thanks for all the input.